# HTML/CSS drop down menu (hover)

Tags: html, css

hi I am having trouble with my dropdown menu.

Here is the HTML code

```
<div class="sticky-nav">
        <a id="mobile-nav" class="menu-nav" href="#menu-nav"></a>

        <div id="logo">
            <a id="goUp" href="index.html" title="CyberSprint"></a>
        </div>

        <nav id="menu">
            <ul id="menu-nav">
                <li><a href="about.html" class="external">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="solutions.html" class="external">Solutions</a>
                    <ul id="submenu-nav">
                        <li><a href="hits.html" class="external"> Healthcare ITSolutions</a></li>
                        <li><a href="gits.html" class="external">Government IT Solutions</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="solutions.html" class="external">Services</a>
                    <ul id="submenu-nav">
                        <li><a href="solutions.html" class="external">Risk Management</a></li>
                        <li><a href="solutions.html" class="external">Audit & Assessment</a></li>
                        <li><a href="solutions.html" class="external">Disaster Recovery & Business Continuity Planning</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="contact.html" class="external">Contact</a></li>
                <li> <a href="javascript:popup()" class="external">Login</a></li>       
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

and here is the CSS code

```
nav#menu {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

nav#menu #menu-nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}

nav#menu #menu-nav li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

nav#menu #menu-nav li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0; 
}

nav#menu #menu-nav li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 60px;
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav#menu #menu-nav li.current a,
nav#menu #menu-nav li a:hover {
    color: #23aae1;
}

nav#menu #menu-nav li ul li {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 48px;
    left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

nav#menu #menu-nav li ul li { 
    background: #555; 
    display: block; 
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}

nav#menu #menu-nav li ul li { 
    background: #666;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: What is the actual problem you are having? I guess you got too occupied to the problem that you forgot to mention what your problem is :)

Answer (score 1):

What is the problem that you are having?

1. You Shouldn't put identical ids in one document.
2. The sub-menus shouldn't be visible:

   ul > li > ul {
        display: none;
   }

Maybe this is what you are looking for?

```
ul > li:hover > ul {
     display: block;
}
```

This is a working example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpJrov

Answer (score 0):

Again, you did not mention what the actual problem was here, but here are a few things I see wrong here...

1: even though you are not calling the ID's in your CSS, your HTML shows multiple elements with the same ID...you shouldn't do that.

2: you have

```
nav#menu #menu-nav li ul li { ... }
```

listed 3 times here. 
   - just add the third one with the first one...
   - the second one is where you are having some of your problems.

for the your

```
nav#menu #menu-nav li ul li { 
background: #555; 
display: block; 
color: #fff;
text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
```

}

block, you need to add :hover after the first li, else this isn't doing anything for you...

3: in your first

```
nav#menu #menu-nav li ul li { ... }
```

block, get rid of

```
visibility:hidden
```

and

```
opacity:0
```

they are not needed here...

after making these changes, I got your code to run just fine; though you will need to adjust the positioning of your nested lists...they are all the way to the left...

hope this helps.